# Is there a $5 \times 5$ matrix with exactly $2$ fun elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> An element of a matrix is called 'fun' if changing this element
> changes the determinant. Is there a $5 \times 5$ matrix with exactly $2$ fun elements?

---

My intuition is that there does not exist such a matrix. I have tried using properties of the determinant to no avail. I have also tried to relate eigenvalues and the characteristic polynomial to this problem, but I'm having trouble relating eigenvalues to specific elements of a matrix. Any help or guidance would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

seems to have cofactor matrix

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: It took me a minute to see how this answers the question. The determinant of this matrix is $0$. If we change just the entry in the top row, leftmost column, the determinant of the matrix changes away from $0$.  If we change just the entry in the next-to-top row, leftmost column, the determinant of the matrix changes away from $0$.  If we change just the one of the remaining entries of this matrix, the determinant stays at $0$. Very nice. +1

Comment: More generally, it can be shown that if $A$ is $5\times5$ matrix with exactly two “fun” elements, either $A$ or $A^T$ is in the form of
$$
P_1\pmatrix{0&0&0&0&0\\ \mathbf u&c\mathbf u&\mathbf v&\mathbf w&\mathbf x}P_2,
$$
where $\mathbf u,\mathbf v,\mathbf w,\mathbf x$ are linearly independent, $c$ is a nonzero scalar and $P_1,P_2$ are some permutation matrices.